# My LCD monitor cycles on and off when I turn on my computer sometimes, makes whirring noise while doing so

Tags: display, hardware-failure

For the past two days, when I've started my desktop computer, the monitor was black and didn't seem to be receiving a signal, so I'd restarted and everything seemed to work normally.  Today, when I started my computer, my monitor's power LED cycled green-orange-unlit, showing brief flashes of my computer's normal start-up routine.  The monitor was also making a "whirring" noise while doing this.  I was able to restart my computer and have it behave normally today, but I'm reasonably certain the monitor is failing.  After the computer has started up and the monitor is displaying normally, it won't behave strangely until the next time I start the computer.

My question is this: **Is it almost certainly my monitor that's failing, or could it be something else like the Graphics card or video cable?**

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit Service Pack 1 and I have an Acer AL2016W for a monitor, two 8 gig sticks of DDR3 RAM, an AMD FX-4100 Quad Core Processor, and an AMD Radeon HD 6800 series graphics card.  I'm not sure what my Motherboard is, but I can find out if necessary.

My monitor is currently running at its native resolution and what appears to be an acceptable screen refresh rate, and I've made sure the video and power cables at both ends are secure, so those aren't the issues.

I eventually ended up replacing the monitor, and the new appears to have none of the problems of the old, but I replaced both cables at the same time as well.  **Could the cables have possibly caused this, or was it the monitor?**

Comment: You can download the user manual and service manual from http://www.manualslib.com/download/233034/Acer-Al2016w.html and http://www.manualslib.com/download/380436/Acer-Al2016.html respectively, though I saw no mention of your issue. Have you checked the current screen resolution setting and frequency to see if the monitor is fully compatible?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Manual says maximum resolution is at 1680x1050, which is what my monitor has always operated at (this is a fairly old monitor and a system that's at least a year old) and Screen Refresh Rate can't actually be chosen to be anything other than 60 Hz, but from what I understand of the manual, the monitor is compatible with that.

Comment: It is almost certainly the monitor which was failing, going by your description of its power LED colours and the noises. In general, if electrical equipment starts making noises which it shouldn't then it is time to get it repaired or replaced.

Comment: It sounds like you solved the problem.  You might want to either make that clear in the question or post an answer that describes how you fixed it.  The problem was not likely the cables.  Bad cables would not cause those symptoms or work normally later.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is no longer reproducible and nothing needs to be solved.

Comment: @fixer1234 The reason I edited in the first place is because I wanted an answer for when this inevitably happens to someone else.  It's still an answerable question and it's clearly on-topic.

Comment: There is no way to know for your monitor or whether the issue is the same for someone else's.  It would all be speculation; it isn't answerable.